# How to capture an entire group consisting out of different characters?

Tags: regex

I have a text with a number that contains dots:

> text 304.33.44.52.03.001 text

where I want to capture the number including strings:

> 304.33.44.52.03.001

The following regex will capture sevaral groups:

```
(\d+\.?)
```

Resulting in:

```
304.
33.
44.
...
```

What is the correct syntax to return the entire number including dots in one result?

Comment: Probably, `\d+(?:\.\d+)*`. `\d[\d.]*` will also work for the above example

Comment: yes that seems to work! Could you please expain it a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d+\.?` matches 1+ digits and then an optional `.` char.

You need to use either

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)*
```

or

```
\d[\d.]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vLgGXX/1)

The `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` pattern matches

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)*` - 0 or more occurrences of a `.` and then 1+ digits. `(?:...)` is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) that is used to group 2 patterns and set a quantifier on their sequence.

The `\d[\d.]*` pattern matches a digit first, and then tries to match 0 or more digits or `.`.

In regex engines that do not support `\d` you need to use a safer pattern, a bracket expression `[0-9]`.